# how to convert a female voice into male voice using python

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, voice, pitch-shifting

Is there any way to convert female voice sound (.wav) into a male voice. I have tried 
 **librosa.effects.pitch_shift** function but its decreasing the sound qaulity and creating too much echo

Might be possible I'm miss handling parameters  so here is the parameters I used

```
y, sr = librosa.load(f3, sr=20000) # orignal sr of file is 22050
y_shifted = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(y, sr, n_steps=-6)
```